# Complete Packing of packets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Complete Packing Problem**

There is a container of width W and height H, There are N rectangle packets, Goal is we have to insert m (m<=n) packets(having w width, h height, and weight =w*h ) into the container such that all

1. packets place close to each other.
2. We can place packet in contact with each other.
3. No packet above other. All packet should touch with container bottom.
4. We can place packet as height level or width level only we have to maximize the weight of packets and the sum of the packet's width equals to width of the container.

Example:
A. Let's consider there is a container of width 16.
B. There are 8 packets, Having

```
  Height  Width   Weight
p1  2      6      12
p2  6      4      24
p3  4      4      16
p4  6      3      18
p5  1      12     12
p6  7      3      21  
p7  3      5      15
p8  5      2      10
```

Now we have to place Packets Such that Sum of the width of packets should be 16. Don't worry about container height.

Possibility 1:

```
          2 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 2 
          w1  h2  w3  w5  w7  h8
    Sum of all=16 equals to Container width
    Weight of conatiner is =(2*6 + 6*4 + 4*4 + 1*12 * 3*5 + 5*2)=89
```

Possibility 2:

```
    6 + 4 + 1+ 5
    h1  h2  w5 h7   
Sum of all =16 equals to container width
Weight of conatiner is (2*6 + 6*4 + 1*12 + 3*5 )=63
```

Other possibilities maybe

SO Output is which combination has maximum weight.

**Here Output is 89.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `knapsack` "variation": we take an element, or not.

#### recursive approach

for the given `v` (each element is a box), and the current total width `s`

we may consider the recursion function
`def recurse(v, s)`

which does:

- if v is empty or s == 0 (we can't fill more boxes) `return {s:0, cost:0}`
- takeout first element of `v` as `(w,h,cost)` (You defined cost as w*h)
- three possibilities:

  - do not take into account the current box

    ```
    p1 = recurse(v, s)
    ```
  - s - w >= 0:

    ```
    r = recurse(v, s-w)
    p2 = {
        s: w+r.s,
        c: cost + r.cost
    }
    ```
  - s - h >= 0:

    ```
    r = recurse(v, s-h)
    p3 = {
        s: h+r.s,
        c: cost + r.cost
    }
    ```

and which returns the minimal `p_i` (according to `p_i.s` first then `p_i.cost`)
you would call it with `recurse(v, 16)`

#### dynamic approach

We may initialize a structure of all the possible sums

Simplest is an array of size 17(for sum == 0 to 16) (referred thereafter as `layer`)

Each element of layer holds: the minimal `cost`, `boxes` used to reach that cost

```
initialize the layer according to the boxes

foreach box(w,h,cost) of v

    nextLayer = copy(layer)

    //layerW is simply the idx of layerEl, aka the sum of width of layerEl.boxes
    forall layerEl, layerW of the layer
        if layerEl.boxes contain box
            //skip that current layerEl
            break

        if layerEl is valid: (it is not an "empty" box due to initialization)
            //we may obtain a new sum: box.w + layerEl.w
            //that new sum can be compared to layer[ box.w + layerW ]
            //update layer[ box.w + layerW ] only if
            //* layer[ box.w + layerW ] is invalid
            //* OR its cost is greater
            if update:
                nextLayer[ box.w + layerW ] = {
                    cost: box.cost + layerEl.cost,
                    boxes: box U layerW.boxes
                }

            //do the same with box.h
    layer = nextLayer
//got it: layer[16]
```

at the end, we have used all boxes (or not) of `v`, and we can just take the 16th el of layer

below is the standard recursion (with memoization (`cache`)); and the dp implem

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369646/complete-packing-of-packets
//==> find all sums which give width, and take the lowest weight
var v =     [[2,6],[6,4],[4,4],[6,3],[1,12],[7,3],[3,5],[1,2]];
var costs=  [12,    24,   16,   18,     12,  21,    15,  10];
var maxW = 16;

var cache = {};
function rec(v, depth, w){
    if(depth == -1 || w == 0)return {w:0, cost: 0, v:[]};

    let id = depth+'-'+w;
    if(cache[id])return cache[id];

    //don't take current
    let best = rec(v, depth-1, w);

    let [a,b] = v[depth];
    let cost = costs[depth];
    let sorted = [a,b].map(el=>{
        if( w - el >= 0){
            //we can take el
            let res = rec(v, depth-1, w-el);
            return {
                w: el + res.w,
                cost: cost + res.cost,
                v: [el].concat(res.v)
            }
        }
    }).filter(x=>!!x);

    if(sorted.length){

        //minimize w, and for equal w, select the minimal weight
        best = sorted.concat(best).sort((a,b)=>{
            if(a.w < b.w){
                return 1;
            }
            if(a.w > b.w){
                return -1;
            }
            return a.cost - b.cost;
        })[0];
    }

    cache[id] = best;
    return best;
}

console.log(rec(v, v.length-1, maxW));


function dp(){
    //make all sums up to width
    //for an indentical width, select the one with lowest weight
    //ith idx in layer means width==i, 
    //ith element holds the optimal "combination" (minimal cost) leading to that width
    let layer = new Array(maxW+1).fill(0).map(w=>Object.assign({},{cost:1000}));
    v.forEach((elems,i)=>{
        let cost = costs[i];
        elems.forEach(el=>{
            if(layer[el].cost == 1000 || layer[el].cost > cost){
                layer[el] = {cost: cost, s:new Set([el]), indices:new Set([i])}
            }
        })
    });
    for(var i = v.length-1; i>=0; --i){
        let [a,b] = v[i];
        let cost = costs[i];
        let next = layer.slice(0);
        layer.forEach((c,w)=>{
            //the current (width)sum is not yet valid, hammer time
            if(c.cost == 1000)return;

            //you cannot use yourself twice (v[i] + initialization)
            if(c.indices.has(i)){return}
            [a,b].forEach(el=>{

                if(w + el > maxW){
                    return;
                }

                let best = layer[w+el];
                //lhs sum is valid, and can override an invalid sum (layer[w+el].cost==1000)
                if( cost + layer[w].cost < layer[w+el].cost || layer[w+el].cost==1000){
                    best = {cost: cost + layer[w].cost, 
                        s:new Set([el].concat([...layer[w].s])),
                        indices: new Set([i].concat([...layer[w].indices]))
                    }
                }
                next[w + el] = best;
            });
        });

        layer = next;
    }
    return layer[maxW];
}
let res = dp();
console.log({cost:res.cost, v:[...res.s], indices:[...res.indices]});
```